# how to mark something unstored

Tags: java, siena

In the Siena is a persistence API for Java, how would one annotate that a field is not persisted??

See https://github.com/mandubian/siena/wiki/Manuals

Comment: Tried @Transient?? And what is that link for?

Answer (score 0):

According to [The docs.oracle.com Java Tutorial on Bean Persistence](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/advanced/persistence.html)...

> To exclude fields from serialization in a Serializable object mark the fields with the transient modifier.
>
> ```
> transient int status;
> ```
>
> Default serialization will not serialize transient and static fields.

... so I don't think you annotate that, but if you did I'd bet it was with the [`Transient` annotation](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/beans/Transient.html).

Comment: Well, he's talking about storing in Database.. And I'm not sure whether it would work with that.. Will it??

Comment: @Rohit Jain - Not sure either... but the doc I linked to is about persistence; if it doesn't apply to database persistence, I think someone needs to get fired :P

Comment: Haha :)... Yeah you are right..